# JQuery Isotope not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-isotope

I have added the JQuery plugin [Isotopte](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html) to [my site](http://clarkeconstructions.com.au/homev2.html).

It works but only after the browser resizes. The images just seem to stack up on each other before hand.

My code to is:

```
$(function(){
$('#isotopecontainer').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.frontitem',
        masonry: {
        }
 });
});
```

I've tried adding columnWidth as the site suggests but this makes no difference.

Im really not sure what is going on. Can anyone help me out at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly where your issue is but I got a working solution.

[Working solution (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/7kUfa/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#isotopecontainer').isotope({
        // options
       itemSelector : '.frontitem',
       masonry : {}
       });
    }
);
```

It has all of your options but I can't seem to find exactly where your code is wrong. I did use the document ready callback that jquery supplies however I don't think that was the issue.

Also make sure you include jquery before isotope.

Comment: Ah I think the key difference is that you have specified the height for the divs

Comment: Maybe.  When I copied your code I was getting a "method isotope not found" so idk

Comment: Yes - I have added a height to the images and that fixes it.